# How to get an array of object arrays from a hashmap values?

Tags: java, hashmap

Please forgive for not elaborating the question well. I am sure the example below will tell you what i mean. I need to get all values of anObject from a hashmap. As u can see from the example below, the key would be anObject and the value would be an array of anObject.

```
HashMap<anObject,anObject[]> testMap = new HashMap<anObject,anObject[]>(); //Define map

anObject someObject1 = new anObject("one");
anObject someObject2 = new anObject("two")

anObject[] manyObjects1 = new anObject[3];
manyObjects1[0] = new anObject(0);
manyObjects1[1] = new anObject(1);
manyObjects1[2] = new anObject(2);
anObject[] manyObjects2 = new anObject[3];
manyObjects2[0] = new anObject(0);
manyObjects2[1] = new anObject(1);
manyObjects2[2] = new anObject(2);

testMap.put(someObject1,manyObjects1);
testMap.put(someObject2,manyObjects2);

//Get anObject from all the values put into testMap
anObject[] getAllValues1 = (anObject[])testMap.values().toArray; //is this correct or
anObject[][] getAllValues2 = (anObject[][])testMap.values().toArray; //is this correct
```

Comment: Neither of those will even compile.

Comment: Prefer collections (List, Set, etc.) over arrays. No need to transform them into arrays: they can be iterated directly, and have a whole lot of useful methods and features that arrays don't have.

Comment: yea i need help lol. Thats why i post

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

```
Collection values = testMap.values();
anObject[][] getAllValues2 = (anObject[][])values.toArray(new anObject[values.size()][]);
```

Because you're getting back an array of the values in the map, and the values in the map are arrays, you need to indicate you're getting back an array of arrays, so `[][]`.

Comment: @user859385: No worries. Note the edit, turns out you need the cast on the return from `toArray`.

Comment: it turns out it doesnt work :(. seems like i have a bracket or some sort missing
Station[][] allValues = values.toArray(Station[][values.size()]);